# ¿Solucion al plugin de WordPress: problema con js_composer?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp, wordpress-plugin

Tengo el problemas que cuando inicio la pagina para editar con el plugin me aparece este error:

Warning: Illegal string offset ‘content’ in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxx\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\include\classes\editors\class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 912

Intenté actualizar el complemento pero no me funciona. Si alguien más sabe. Sería un gran favor.

```
/**
 * @param $content
 * @param bool $is_container
 * @param bool $parent_id
 *
 * @since 4.2
 * @return string
 */
function parseShortcodesString( $content, $is_container = false, $parent_id = false ) {
    $string = '';
    preg_match_all( '/' . self::shortcodesRegexp() . '/', trim( $content ), $found );
    WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
    add_shortcode( 'vc_container_anchor', 'vc_container_anchor' );

    if ( count( $found[2] ) === 0 ) {
        return $is_container && strlen( $content ) > 0 ? $this->parseShortcodesString( '[vc_column_text]' . $content . '[/vc_column_text]', false, $parent_id ) : $content;
    }
    foreach ( $found[2] as $index => $s ) {
        $id = md5( time() . '-' . $this->tag_index ++ );
        $content = $found[5][ $index ];
        $shortcode = array(
            'tag' => $s,
            'attrs_query' => $found[3][ $index ],
            'attrs' => shortcode_parse_atts( $found[3][ $index ] ),
            'id' => $id,
            'parent_id' => $parent_id,
        );
        if ( false !== WPBMap::getParam( $s, 'content' ) ) {
            $shortcode['attrs']['content'] = $content; //Este es el problema 
        }
        $this->post_shortcodes[] = rawurlencode( json_encode( $shortcode ) );
        $string .= $this->toString( $shortcode, $content );
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: necesitas actualizar el theme que introdujo ese plugin, por lo general es un theme de wpbakery antes llamado visual composer ( de ahi que el plugin sea js_composer ). si el theme no tiene actualizacion disponible podes intentar adquirir un theme que si tenga actualizacion ( compatible php 8 ) no es necesario sea el mismo theme  y en la carpeta del bundle vas a encontrar un `js_composer.zip` actualizado, mueve la carpeta del js_composer ( o renombra ) y descomprime el nuevo plugin en su lugar ( instalar desde el zip sobre el plugin antiguo no siempre resulta )

Comment: Era por falta de actualización del plugin jajaja y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: en ocasiones que el plugin viene como bundle de un theme, se dan situaciones que no deja actualizar ( hay q buscar el .zip y reemplazar), bien q lo pudiste resolver

Answer (score -1):

Los mensajes de advertencia no significan que haya un problema con su sitio web. Lo que puedes hacer es agregar estas dos líneas:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

hasta el final del archivo `wp-config.php` en su sitio web

Comment: Sobre ese problema, puse las 2 lineas de código y me sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: Estas eguro que no has repedido lineas ?   Es decir wordpress por defecto  ya trae esas lineas. solo debes modificarlas

Comment: Ya vi cual era el problemas y era por la actualización de ese plugin, de la cual encontré una versión mas avanzada. Pero de todas formas gracias por la ayuda.